# Pushing changes to a github repo without having to pull

Tags: github

So I've recently started using github and made my own repo and pushed a project there. I understand that to fix the error saying "Remote repository contains unmerged into the local branch", you must pull or fetch.

The problem is that I made some major changes (remade file hiearchy, removed some files and added some as well) and now I do not want to pull since it would add back the files I removed and now, whenever I push, the error mentioned above pops up. How do I push the changes I made then?

Comment: There may be no avoiding the friction caused by the changes you made versus the original source branch.  The typical workflow you would use in GitHub would be for you to just push your branch to the remote, and then create a pull request back to the original source branch.  Then, it would be up to you (or someone else) to bring the feature branch up to date with the source via a merge or rebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [force push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---force) the changes you have made
`git push --force origin branch_name`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [Git stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) is what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have made some changes then that will automatically get applied on top of the remote changes. So if you take a pull, still you will see your changes on top.

Comment: well you see, if I pull, the files I deleted come back so I can't pull. I've tried sadly